# Benefit to specific syntax?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In google apps script, is there any benefit to writing

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive;
var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
```

in two lines, instead of

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive.getSheets()[0];
```

in one line?

In my mind, there is more benefit (less code!) in example 2...

Correct? I understand that a two-line construction may be necessary depending on the details of the script, but if all things were equal, why not use a one-line statement if possible?

Comment: It looks that you are asking about [tag:coding-styles] but this kind off questions are not allowed as tend to be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: I think that in your script, `SpreadsheetApp.getActive` is `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`.

Comment: Real benefit is to use variable ss later. If you dont intend to use it, the second variant seems to be better.